# Why is hydra only trying one password?

Tags: security, passwords

I recently downloaded hydra for my windows computer. This is my first attempt in password cracking. I’m [trying to crack on step 4](https://attack.samsclass.info/brute.htm) there is a login form designed for cracking.

In the hydra command promt I type the following to crack the password.

```
hydra -l admin -p Desktop/passlist.txt attack.samsclass.info http-get-form "/brute4.php:login=^USER^&pin=^PASS^:Denied
```

It returns:

```
[DATA] max 1 task per 1 server, overall 1 tasks, 1 login try (l:1/p:1), ~1 try per task
[DATA] attacking service http-get-form on port 80
[DATA] with additional data /brute4.php:login=^USER^&pin=^PASS^:Denied
1 of 1 target completed, 0 valid passwords found
```

On my password list specified, i have the correct password but hydra is only trying one password and then stopping. what can i do to change this?

Comment: Is the password it’s attempting contained in the text file?

Comment: how could i fix this? the passlist,txt just has a bunch of passwords. I hit enter everytime after adding a new password. would that cause an error? should i seperate them with commas or something? sorry, im super new to this XD

Answer (score 2):

You probably know the answer by now but the problem is that your `-p` flag is telling Hydra to attempt the text that comes immediately after it as the password - which in this case is `Desktop/passlist.txt`.

If you want Hydra to use the text file as a source you need to capitalize the letter, i.e. `-P`.